# Fetch website specific category URL based on store id in custom module

Tags: category, magento2.2.2

I am working on fetching category URL for stores which are part of two different websites on a multiwebsite setup i.e abc.com and abc.co.uk, Issue happens when I fetch URL for abc.co.uk it returns me the URL of abc.com only. I have tried fetching with below solutions but none of them has worked:

1) Here in collection factory class I used is as below and latter is the code

> \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category

```
$collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->getCollection()->setStoreId($storeId)->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addIsActiveFilter();
```

2) I looped through all the categories and tried fetching it from repository

`$this->categoryRepository->get($category->getEntityId(), $storeId);`

3) Another solution tried with looping the categories fetched based on store id, looping it and generating URL as below, Although below URL provides me with a solution for correct website URL but still the category URL path is incorrect.

```
$this->storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl().$category->getUrlPath().$category->getUrlKey().$categoryUrlSuffix;
```

Any help or guidance on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this will help you:**

```
protected $_store;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $store,
    $data = []
) {
    $this->_store = $store;
    parent::__construct($data);
}

$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categories = $categoryFactory->create()                              
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // for all attribute
    ->setStore($this->_store->getStore()); //categories from current store will be fetched

foreach ($categories as $category){
    $category->getUrlKey();
}
```

Comment: Already tried with Resourcemodel after posting question but that hasn't worked as well it still returns the old URL only!

Comment: sorry but old Url means ? in this code give you store wise url @mp196

Comment: As mentioned in my question i have two domains abc.com and abc.co.uk while fetching url for abc.co.uk it provides me the abc.com category url only.

Comment: so you just check what your abc.co.uk domain store id and pest in code like setStore(2)